# Rigging a leg that stick on the floor

Tags: rigging

I'm learning how to rig and for my little project I want to rig a leg (a robot). I have a rig for hip to knee. Another one from knee to heel. Then one from heel to the start of toes. And the last one for the toes. I can make my leg with my rigs and I've found how to avoid the feet to cross the floor. But I would like this result:

- I would like the last rig that can't cross to the floor sticks to the floor when I move the leg.
- At the same times, I would like the heel can take off the floor when I move the hip to the top.

I guess there is something to do this simple thing but I guess I didn't found it.

Comment: Have you tried using Inverse Kinematics?

Comment: Yes, but may be I don't use it like I should... When I use IK, the leg last bone stay stick at the end of the led. And I would like only the before last bone stays stick on the floor.

Comment: I believe, that it's better to start with prepared rigging system like Rigify https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pAhbO7U1ID8&ab_channel=THELUWIZART For small project it should be enough